# Vim regex to replace only datetime

Tags: regex, vim

I want to replace each line by the datetime string inside each.

Input

```
D­¬ng ThÞ Anh 19/02/1992 TH12B 10.0 5.0
La C«ng TuÊn Anh 30/01/1995 TH12A 8.5 6.5
NguyÔn §øc Anh 14/10/1995 TH12B 10.0 5.5
Ph1m Tïng Anh 10/04/1994 HTTT11 1.0 4.5
```

Output

```
19/02/1995
30/06/1995
14/11/1995
10/03/1994
```

I tried with the following command:

```
:'<,'>s/[^=\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}]/ /g
```

But there's something wrong.

What I have to change to make the command work?

Comment: Not fancy but this would work `%s/\v.{-}(\d+\/\d+\/\d+).*$/\1`.

Comment: In order to avoid a lot of backslashes, we can use another delimiter 
`:%s,\v.{-}(\d+/\d+/\d+).*$,\1`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply "negate" the regular expression; for some cases, an inverted pattern can be written, but this is not a general solution.

Instead, you have to *match the entire line* and *capture the text to be kept*. In the replacement part of `:substitute`, just refer to the captured group (`\1`). This is a common pattern:

```
%s#.*\<\(\d\+/\d\+/\d\+\)\>.*#\1#
```

Note: I've used `#` delimiters here to avoid the escaping of the `/` occurring in the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Just look for

```
\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}
```

and replace the lines. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/XCco1R/1/).

Comment: I want to keep the datetime strings. If follow your regex, the datetime strings  are replaced. Am I wrong?